# Как разбить блок на две независимые части

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я хочу разбить `bar-line` на две части *(1 и 2 как на прикрепленном рисунке)* и работать с ними уже отдельно как с `flex` элементами
HTML:

```
<div class="top-bar">
    <div class="bar-line" >
        <img class="bar-line-left" src="Vector.png">
        <div class="bar-line-right">
            some text
        </div>
        <div class="bar-line-right">
            some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="top-bar-clone">
    <!--Clone div with nonabsolute position-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4%;
    background-image: url("Rectangle.png");
    padding : 1%;
}
.top-bar-сlone {
    position: static;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
}

.bar-line {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
}
.bar-line-right {
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: flex;
}

.bar-line-left{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Вот как это выглядит:
[image: Вот как это выглядит сейчас]

А вот как хотелось бы, где внутри 1 лежит `bar-line-left`, а внутри 2 `bar-line-right`
[image: Макет ожидаемого]

Comment: если правильно вас поняла, то нужно два контейнера внутри bar-line - для левой и для правой части. а в правой части уже создавать необходимое количество блоков.

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно сделать 2 блока, а внутри правого уже разместить нужное количество элементов, ему также можно задать `display: flex` если требуется горизонтальное расположение или какое либо выравнивание.

```css
.bar-line {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.bar-line__left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #9FEE00;
}

.bar-line__right {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #9FEE00;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-line">
  <div class="bar-line__left">some img</div>
  
  <div class="bar-line__right">
    <div class="bar-line__right-text">some text</div>
    <div class="bar-line__right-text">some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```